# Kafka API: java.io.IOException: Can't resolve address: 357d78957cf5:9092

Tags: scala, apache-kafka

I am trying to figure out how to properly write a simple producer application to Kafka.

1)  Please tell me if I should avoid using 0.10.0.1, I am totally struggled with it.

This example I found from Apache wiki worked for 0.8 
https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/0.8.0+Producer+Example

It’s completely different in 0.10 
http://kafka.apache.org/documentation#producerconfigs

So this is what I am using: 
"org.apache.kafka" % "kafka_2.10" % "0.10.0.1",

I am feeling very bad about this latest Kafka library, because apparently there are some known issues. In the runtime, it even shows a list of warnings about some configurations are not known config. But if I don’t provide them, the app won’t run. On github, people have identified this kind of issue.

2)  Honestly, my code is super simple, if their documentation is even right.

```scala
    val props = new Properties()
    props.put("bootstrap.servers", "192.168.99.100:9092");
    props.put("key.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer")
    props.put("key.deserializer","org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer");
    props.put("value.serializer","org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");
    props.put("value.deserializer","org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer");
    props.put("producer.type", "async")
    props.put("advertised.listeners", "192.168.99.100:32777")

    val producer = new KafkaProducer[String, String](props)
    val t = System.currentTimeMillis()
    val runtime = new Date().getTime();
    val msg = runtime + ", hello world";
    val message = new ProducerRecord[String, String](topic, null, msg)
    producer.send(message);
```

I am running 2 separate Docker containers for zookeeper (192.168.99.100:32777) and Kafka (192.168.99.100:9092). The settings work. I can use Kafka command line create a producer and consumer properly. However, trying to write my own client doesn’t work.

First, their document doesn’t even say **advertised.listeners** is required or part of the ProducerConfig. But without it, I encountered this exception “Give up sending metadata request since no node is available”. So I found this page: [cann't connect to kafka server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34572621/cannt-connect-to-kafka-server)

Once I added “**advertised.listeners**” (because according to Apache document, “**advertised.host.name**” has been deprecated). I encountered this infinite exceptions: “java.io.IOException: Can't resolve address: 357d78957cf5:9092”

I honestly don’t know where that address come from. In the terminal, it clearly shows it’s using my docker container IP:

[image]

And then I found this: [Kafka 0.8.2.2 - Unable to publish messages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33541114/kafka-0-8-2-2-unable-to-publish-messages)
I think it’s the right answer to my problem, but I really don’t know what I am supposed to do to fix this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some backgrounds you'll find useful before using the producer: The old producer(Scala) in 0.8.x had already been removed starting 0.9.0.

Therefore, you are using the new producer(Java) now. Kafka dev team decides to remove any Zookeeper dependencies from the new client, no matter producer or consumer. So you should not set the ZK setting anymore. Besides, letting "advertised.listeners" point to ZK service is incorrect.

"advertised.listeners" is for IaaS machines which usually have more than one NICs. Here is what Kafka doc says about it:

> In IaaS environments, this may need to be different from the interface to which the broker binds. If this is not set, the value for `listeners` will be used.

You could set this parameter to have client bind the public NIC, whereas the intra-communication for brokers binds the private NIC.

Comment: very useful background. thanks for that. But it doesn't solve my problem. Without setting "advertised.listeners", I encountered this exception “Give up sending metadata request since no node is available”.

Comment: The reason why you are seeing this exception is because there is no available node in your cluster or client failed to connect to the broker.

Check your listeners setting. Besides, make sure hostname or IPs should be used for both server settings and client settings. Do not mix them up.

Comment: sorry, I am very new in this topic so I am still very confused. What is the available node you are referring to? The docker container IP? I don't want to go too complicated, so there is no cluster in the docker (no swarm), only one container is running. I have manually created a topic inside the kafka container. and how do I set "hostname or IPs" and what is the server setting and what is the client setting here? thanks!

Comment: actually, I start figuring out what you meant now. I have to tell Kafka docker container what advertised_host_name is. I have to create a YML file, which contains this  environment:  KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME: 192.168.99.100

Answer (score 0):

You have to add a host map.

In mac

```
vi /etc/hosts
{IP} {String in Error}
192.168.99.100 357d78957cf5
```

Now restart the application and test.